# Two Tableviews in One view controller and One tableview not working when setting DS for 2nd one

Tags: ios, iphone

I have two tableviews in one view controller.
One is there in the interface builder and the other i have created dynamically using the below code in the viewDidLoad() method.

```
// Creating the view for placing the dynamic tableview

-(UIView *) createAndAddMenuView :(float) viewHeight
{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    CGRect coord = myView.frame;
    coord.origin.x = -255;
    coord.origin.y = 0;
    coord.size.width = 255;
    coord.size.height = viewHeight;
    [myView setFrame:coord];

    return  myView;
}

-(void) addMenuItemsTable{

    UITableView *dynamicTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 255, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    dynamicTable.delegate=self;
    dynamicTable.dataSource=self;
    dynamicTable.tag = 20;
    //[dynamicTable reloadData];
    [menuView addSubview:dynamicTable];
}
```

Both these two tableviews have delegate and datasource set to self. The second dynamic tableview is added to a view and placed on the left hidden side with x = -255.
When I click on the button in the navigation bar i am moving "menuView" view to the screen and the other static tableview out of the screen just like the Facebook app.

I am using this code for moving the menuView back and forth.

```
-(void) toggleMainView :(UITableView *) mytableView withMenuView : (UIView * )menuView{

NSLog(@"TAG %d",mytableView.tag);
CGRect destination = mytableView.frame;
 NSLog(@"XX %f",destination.origin.x);
if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
    destination.origin.x = 0;
} else {
    destination.origin.x += 255;
}

NSLog(@"ORG X = %f", destination.origin.x );

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

    [self showMenu:menuView];
    mytableView.frame = destination;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    mytableView.userInteractionEnabled = !(destination.origin.x > 0);

}];
}

-(void)showMenu :(UIView *)menuView{

CGRect coord = menuView.frame;
NSLog(@"Width = %f, x = %f",coord.size.width, coord.origin.x);
if(coord.origin.x < 0){
    coord.origin.x = 0;

}else{
    coord.origin.x = -255;
}
[menuView setFrame:coord];

}
```

But when I am NOT setting the second tableview Datasource then only this code is working.
I have no idea why this is happening.

ie. When I comment out this line

dynamicTable.dataSource=self;

Then only when I click the button the first tableview is moving out of the screen.
All these times the dynamic one will move back and forth in the screen.
When the DS is not commented the first (static tableview) will not move and Second (dynamic one) will move.

This is my first iPhone application.

Comment: Please elaborate on "But when I am NOT setting the second tableview Datasource then only this code is working"

Comment: @mackworth :- I have edited the post to add more explanation

Comment: @Vipin your explanation is not elaborate enough. Please add the full source code or try to explain your question better.

Comment: is your issue resolved

Comment: @Charan Giri :- No, Please help. I am stuck in this.

Comment: how many tableviews you have. if 2 tableviews how are they allocated option 1: 2 tableview allocated. option 2: 1 tableview allocated and in it you are trying to show two different information(in this case are you using two tag values) please let me know which option you are using

Comment: I have 1 in the interface builder and the other is in a view created dynamically. The 2nd tablview inside this view is also dynamic. when app launches this view is set to x = -255, so dynamic tblview is not shown. when I click a button in the nag bar. i am setting table.x = 255; and dynamicview.x = 0; so 2nd tableview become visible. but when i set DS to self for 2nd tblview, this transition is not happening in this function "toggleMainView", only dynamic view is moving.

Comment: By using tags i was able to set different values in two tableviews.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on delegate and datasource, and check it is getting called or not for both tableview.

Comment: I recreated app with your code as given, and guessed at the rest, and had no problem with the two tables shifting left and right with or without datasource set. The only thing I fixed was at `viewDidLoad` time, `navigationController.view.frame.size.height` is not set yet, so it defaults to zero. Instead I set it to a fixed 420 for now.  So your code so far is fine.  If changing the datasource affects the animation, then something is probably wrong with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Please post this code; take out the labels/data part if it's complicated, but leave in the cell stuff.

Comment: Oh, just checking. Do you have any of the optional datasource routines defined? indexTitles, titleforHeader, etc? If so, comment them out and see if that affects it.

Comment: @mackworth :- As you said I changed the height to 420 for now. Still I am not able to get the effect box first time 1st tblview will slide, on 2nd click the 2nd tblview will slide. then on 3rd both will slide back. So not up to..

Comment: Can you post the IBAction that calls the toggleMainView?  Also, does changing the datasource still make it work?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 2 tableview or 1 tableview try to set tag values for it with two different values suppose for table1 tag is 50 and for table2 tag is 60 then the code in tableview delegates and datasource should be like below.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView.tag==50) // if you have 2 different objects for tableviews then you can also use like this if(tableView == tableviewObjc1)
{
// tableview1 info
}
else
{
// tableview2 info
}
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}    
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
   [view removeFromSuperview];
}
if(tableView.tag==50)
{
// tableview1 info
}
else
{
// tableview2 info
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: :- This is not about setting values. The animation is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any custom control that suits your requirement
from cocoacontrols one of them is

[MVYSideMenu](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu)

**You don't require to add two tableview in one ViewController**

**You should try below approach:**

**STEPS:**

1. Add two Prototype cells to storybaord
2. Make two custom cell class subclassing UITableViewCell and design your cell storyboard or via code
3. cellForRowAtIndexPath: initialize cell according to requirement and set it datasource and delegate methods accordingly

Comment: He's looking for the sliding animation, like the facebook app, where the menu slides in from the left and pushes the data to the right.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for animation only. When I place two Tableviews and setting delegate and ds for both to self, its not sliding..